# How to highlight an arraylist item when touched

Tags: java, android, arrays, arraylist

I'll really appreciate if anyone can help me through this!

**What I did**

1) I draw a shape with canvas in View class.

2) I create array lists of random numbers.

**My Problem**

I want when each item of my array list is touched, it gets highlighted.

I've searched a lot but I can't find any answer or question that matched what I need!

I'm very new in Android.

Here's the part of my code that I used for creating an array list of random numbers:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class YeknafareActivity_layout extends View {
    Paint black_paintbrushstroke;
    Path path = new Path();
    ArrayList<Integer> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    int rand;
}
```

and in the constructor:

```
public YeknafareActivity_layout(Context context, AttributeSet atrs) {
    super(context, atrs);

    black_paintbrushstroke = new Paint();
    black_paintbrushstroke.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    black_paintbrushstroke.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    black_paintbrushstroke.setStrokeWidth(4);
    black_paintbrushstroke.setTextSize(25);

    for (int i = 1; i <= 10;) {
        rand = ((int) (Math.random() * 100) + 1);
        if (!arrayList.contains(rand)) {
            arrayList.add(rand);
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

also, I show this arraylist with drawtext as well.

so Should I use onTouchEvent for solving this problem or the solution is something else? & How?

Comment: where's android source code?

Comment: Why did you draw this shape? Where do you display this array list? Recycler view, list view?

Comment: I edit the source code @redAllocator

Comment: this shape is an environment of my game & array list is inside the shape. I use the custom view. @KirillStarostin
the important part of my code that needs to solve the problem is posted. thanks.

Comment: Is there anybody who can guide me & solve this problem ?!